# How to populate Room database without RecyclerView in Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dagger-hilt

I would like to populate Room database when open first Activity in onCreate method. I am following tutorial where they use RecyclerView. But I just don't need to see data in RecyclerView at the beginning.
How can I populate database withou using RecyclerView.

RestaurantRepository.kt

```
class RestaurantRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val api: RestaurantApi,
    private val db: SybaseDatabase
) {
    private val restaurantDao = db.restaurantDao()

    fun getRestaurants() = networkBoundResource(
        query = {
            restaurantDao.getAllRestaurants()
        },
        fetch = {
            delay(2000)
            api.getRestaurants()
        },
        saveFetchResult = { restaurants ->
            db.withTransaction {
                restaurantDao.deleteAllRestaurants()
                restaurantDao.insertRestaurants(restaurants)
            }

        }
    )
}
```

RestaurantViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class RestaurantViewModel @Inject constructor(
    repository: RestaurantRepository
):ViewModel() {
    val restaurants = repository.getRestaurants().asLiveData()
```

And RestaurantActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class RestaurantActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: RestaurantViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityRestaurantBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val restaurantAdapter = RestaurantAdapter()
        binding.apply {
            recyclerView.apply {
                adapter = restaurantAdapter
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@RestaurantActivity)
            }
            viewModel.restaurants.observe(this@RestaurantActivity) { result ->
                restaurantAdapter.submitList(result.data)

                progressBar.isVisible = result is Resource.Loading && result.data.isNullOrEmpty()
                textViewErrorr.isVisible = result is Resource.Error && result.data.isNullOrEmpty()
                textViewErrorr.text = result.error?.localizedMessage

            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Dao.kt

```
Import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Query
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

@Dao
interface SybaseDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertRestaurants(restaurant: List<Restaurant>)

@Query("DELETE FROM restaurants")
suspend fun deleteAllRestaurants()

@Query("SELECT * FROM restaurants")
fun getAllRestaurants(): Flow<List<Restaurant>>
```

This is model class

```
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "restaurants")
data class Restaurant (
    @PrimaryKey val name: String,
    val type: String,
    val logo: String,
    val address: String
)
```

Actually I have more model classes but they look similar. What I want is to first populate the database and in other Activity I want to recieve data to RecyclerView. I will have like three activities with different RecyclerViews and when user chose the item then new activity is started with data from different table.

Comment: use your model class to get it back from result.data. like Entity myModel=result.data .

Comment: Can you provide some code, please

Comment: livedata returns what kind of data like list?

Comment: You have your data in observer. Use it anyway you want, you do not need to send it to your adapter of RecyclerView.

Comment: @androidLearner yes - this is Dao  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertRestaurants(restaurant: List<Restaurant>)

Comment: @RishabhKumarSingh but the problem is, I don't know how to write the code, just viewModel.restaurants.observe(this) is not enough

Comment: List<Restaurant> restaurant=result.getData();

Comment: @jenik2205 No problem. Can you elaborate what do you want to do with the data in your room database. I will try to provide you some code for that purpose.

Comment: And please include your Dao and model code as well.

Comment: @RishabhKumarSingh I just edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just don't want to load the data from database in your activity, you can change your observer code.

This is your observer code.

```
viewModel.restaurants.observe(this@RestaurantActivity) { result ->
                restaurantAdapter.submitList(result.data)

                progressBar.isVisible = result is Resource.Loading && result.data.isNullOrEmpty()
                textViewErrorr.isVisible = result is Resource.Error && result.data.isNullOrEmpty()
                textViewErrorr.text = result.error?.localizedMessage

            }
```

This line is responsible for loading the data into your RecyclerView adapter. If you omit this line you will have an empty activity in your case.

```
restaurantAdapter.submitList(result.data)
```

Remember, `result` cotains the data from your database which is a List in this case. In fact you should remove the observer code if you don't have to use the data in your activity.

Since you further want to populate your database in the onCreate of first activity. You will require List(say allRestaurants) data you want to insert in the database. You will have to create methods in viewmodel and repository which will insert the data into database.

You will call the viewmodel's method like:

```
viewModel.insertAllRestaurants(allRestaurants)
```

Inside your viewmodel, you will have to call repository's method for inserting the data.

```
fun insertAllRestaurants(allRestaurants:List<Restaurant>)
{
  repository.insertAllRestaurants(allRestaurants)
}
```

Inside your repository, you will have to invoke your `insertRestaurants(restaurant: List<Restaurant>)`.

Comment: @jenik2205 Happy to know that. You may accept this answer using that tick button on the answer.